# Windows 7 doesn't keep drive shares

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, external-hard-drive

I have a external drive array attached via eSata to my computer. I share this drive out on the network so that I can access the files on my other computer. However, the drive always loses its share after a few days and has to be setup again. I usually turn the drive off at night and the computers are often on without the drive being on.

Any ideas? Both computers are Windows 7 x64 Pro.

Answer (score 2):

You want to leave the drive on and seeing if your settings are still changing after that.

Here's a link that has some troubleshooting tips at the end of it (as well as some other information about the shared drives) that you might find some help in:

> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Share-files-with-someone

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm, well that document doesn't really address the issue I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

When you attach a harddrive, it gets a drive letter, namely, `H:`

Don't share `H:`. Make a folder, namely, `D:\Shares` and share it. Inside that folder make a [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29) to `H:`

E.g.

```
cd D:\Shares
mklink /j ExtDrive H:\
```